# Recent achievements button opens a stackexchange.com page if clicked too quickly

Tags: discussion, bug

Today (01/09/2021) there are some new UI improvements in the Stack Overflow website. The problem is sometimes when I press the recent achievements button it redirects to the Stack Exchange profile, which is not the expected output. Is this a bug or a result of feature improvement?

However, I would say it's not that user-friendly.

[image]

Comment: You're pressing it too quickly, you need to wait until the page has fully loaded, this happens to me on mobile as well when I'm on a slower connection than my desktop and I click it before the page load completes.

Comment: This is by design. It's a fallback mechanism when the JavaScript fails to load (or in this case, hasn't loaded completely). That's also why "middle-clicking" (or right-clicking it and opening in a new tab) also opens the network-wide reputation tab.

Comment: Is it possible to handle that without redirection?

Comment: @INDRAJITH Note that this fallback also works if users have their JavaScript disabled. Having this fallback in place is actually goot UX. I’m not sure how you would want to remove the redirection.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+inbox+menu+redirects+to+global+inbox) of [Don't have topbar links open my global profile when the page isn't fully loaded](/q/365998/4642212).